# DigitalOcean NFS vs do-block storage

Tags: kubernetes, digital-ocean

I'm new to DigitalOcean and K8S and can't seem to wrap my head around this:

If I need to run multiple replica of Nginx containers, should I use block storage or NFS storage? I want static html data share by all the NGINX containers running in separate pods.
From my understanding, if I want to share data across multiple pods, I should be using NFS.
Taken from https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-readwritemany-rwx-persistent-volumes-with-nfs-on-digitalocean-kubernetes

*The digitalocean-csi integrates a Kubernetes cluster with the DigitalOcean Block Storage product. A developer can use this to dynamically provision Block Storage volumes for containerized applications in Kubernetes. However, applications can sometimes require data to be persisted and shared across multiple Droplets. DigitalOcean’s default Block Storage CSI solution is unable to support mounting one block storage volume to many Droplets simultaneously. This means that this is a ReadWriteOnce (RWO) solution, since the volume is confined to one node. The Network File System (NFS) protocol, on the other hand, does support exporting the same share to many consumers. This is called ReadWriteMany (RWX), because many nodes can mount the volume as read-write. We can therefore use an NFS server within our cluster to provide storage that can leverage the reliable backing of DigitalOcean Block Storage with the flexibility of NFS shares.*

Any clarification would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you consider creating container images that contain static content inside? Then you won't need any of persistent storage solutions.

Comment: @HelloWorld Why negative score? I was asking a simple question. If you didn't want to answer please don't. Don't ruin my score. Please consider reversing your negative score. What if I've 3 replica pods? I don't want to create 3 different static content.

Comment: The -1 is because its not clear what you are asking for. Are you looking for a solution to presented problem or for an explaination/clarification of differences between block storage and NFS storage, and when to use one. Also, you wrote: "From my understanding, if I want to share data across multiple pods, I should be using NFS" - so the way you presented it suggests that there are only these two options. What I am trying to show you is that there is a third option that may be better for your usecase.